# How to code for generate multiple sets of random number?

Tags: java

How to code if the sets of random numbers can be indicated by users? I am now having java program for generating one set of random numbers, I want to add the function that I can indicate how many sets of random numbers generated. How can I do? Please help.

```
int[] numberSet = new int[6];
int   randomNumber;
boolean duplicate;
//input


//processing
for (int i=0; i<numberSet.length; i++){
    duplicate = false;
    randomNumber = generateRandomValue();
    
    


//output
System.out.println("The numbers for the set : ");
for (int i=0; i<numberSet.length; i++){
    if(i==(numberSet.length-1)){
        System.out.print( numberSet[i]);
    }
    else{
        System.out.print( numberSet[i] + ", ");
    }
    
}

System.out.println("");
}



public static int generateRandomValue(){
return (int) (Math.random()*49) + 1 ;
}
```

Comment: How did you try to solve the problem? What problems did you run into? Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Also: the code you posted is very hard to ready, because the indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some thing like this :

```
    public static int[] generateRandomValueSet(int n){
       Set<Integer> set = new HashSet();
       while(set.size() < n ){
          set.add( (int) (Math.random()*49) + 1);
       }
    
       int[] arr = new int[n];
       int index = 0;
       for(Integer x :set ){
        arr[index++] = x;
       }
       return arr;
    }
```

Comment: The method generateRandomValue(int) in the type MarkSix is not applicable for the arguments () after adding these codes

Comment: You need to call the method with an integer.